# JavaScript, API, filtering array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I want to start function which create me table, iam using `if` and `indexOf` in .foreach, and i wish that shows me the table ony if the value of input will be exactly the same as a first item of array in tah case name:germany.
What iam doing wrong? https://scr.hu/eyjnr0

```
function showCountriesList(resp) {

 var url = 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/';
 var createdTable = createNewTable();
 var countryName = $('#country-name').val();

 resp.forEach(function(item) {
  var row = document.createElement('tr');
  row.innerHTML = `
   <td><img style="width: 60px; height: 60px; object-fit: cover" src=${item.flag}></img></td>
   <td>${item.name}</td>
   <td>${item.capital}</td>
   <td>${item.alpha2Code}</td>
   <td>${item.timezones}</td>
  `;
   if (countryName === url.indexOf([item.name])) {
    createdTable.appendChild(row); }
 });

}
```

Comment: and it is not a full code*

Comment: and I still don't understand what the problem is

Comment: so this part of code is correct? `if (countryName === url.indexOf([item.name])) {
    createdTable.appendChild(row); }` ?

Comment: If the value of countryName will be the same as the first item of API (in that case gemany it will start function createdTable

Comment: beacuse, without `if` you can put for eg. "ger" and you get all different response from server  and all list is showing in table.
If iam typing value "germany" i want see only info about germany, if i type a "ger" it is not a full name so i dont want to see anything

Comment: `countryName` will always be a String ... `url.indexOf(...)` will always be a Number ... a String will **never** === a Number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information you provided is not clear enough to give a conclusive answer.

Your if statement is invalid and will always be false.  Assuming that the *countryName* variable holds a string and the indexOf function returns a number. 
Also your usage if the indexOf function is wrong as it expects a string not an array.

```
if (countryName === url.indexOf([item.name])) {
createdTable.appendChild(row); }
```

I am assuming that the above code is trying to check whether the countryName value is the same as the one in the url.

I suggest you try using the string function [includes](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp)

`if( url.includes(countryName))
      createdTable.appendChild(row);`